# A search for IceCube events in the direction of ANITA neutrino candidates

Tags: astrophysics, neutrinos

In regards to the recent discover by ANITA of space-bound high energy Neutrinos, could this possibly be explained by atmospheric Beta Decay reactions producing these Neutrinos in between the IceCube ANITA trajectory?

Comment: I leaving this paper here for further reading: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.09615.pdf

Answer (score 0):

No, because beta decay never goes above nuclear energies which are at most a few MeV, whereas ANITA observes events as high as EeV (that's exa-electronvolts, as in $10^{18}$eV).